# Is there a built-in typeclass equivalent to this?

Tags: haskell

So I have the following Haskell typeclass used for input validation.

```
-- Check.hs
module Check where
-- Used to ensure that the value of a variable is a good value.  For example, this can be used for input validation.
class Check a where
    accept :: a -> Bool
```

I use it, for example, to ensure that good data is passed to a shopping order.

```
-- Shopping.hs
module Shopping where

import Customer
import Check
import ShoppingItem

-- Stores data about a shopping order including the item
data ShoppingOrder = ShoppingOrder {
        customer :: Customer,       -- The customer placing the order
        item     :: ShoppingItem,   -- The item being ordered
        quantity :: Int             -- The quantity being ordered
        } deriving (Show,Read,Eq)

-- ShoppingItem and Customer both have instances of Check.

instance Check ShoppingOrder where
    accept order = (quantity order) > 0 && (accept . item) order && (accept . customer) order
```

I was wondering if there was already a built-in version of the `Check` typeclass because the nature of data constructors would make it quite useful and I would rather work with already existing API than create my own.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such class, and a quick [Hoogle search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=a+-%3E+Bool&scope=set%3Astackage) doesn't return anything that's part of a typeclass. It doesn't seem useful to have this as part of a typeclass because it would imply that types in that class have a "canonical" predicate associated to them, when it's not obvious that one exists for most types. Your example seems to be driven by some particular business logic rather than anything intrinsic to the type, and I don't see why it's easier to use a class rather than just a custom function.

Comment: Perhaps [`Validity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/validity-0.9.0.1/docs/Data-Validity.html#t:Validity)? It does not map to a `Bool`, but also performs validation.

Comment: My thumb rules about classes: 1) If you need a class for only one instance on a single type, you do not actually need that class. 2) If you need a class for many instances on the same type, you definitely do not need that class. Does any of these apply to your case? I would try to design the program without classes, first, and introduce them as needed.

Comment: @chi I agree, however the OP actually invokes two other `Check` instances from the `instance Check ShoppingOrder`, so it's at least not as suspected just a single type that's ever instantiated.

Comment: Seems more like a smart constructor would be the appropriate pattern here. Rather than checking whether data is valid, make it impossible to construct invalid data in the first place.

Comment: The `Contravariant` package defines `Predicate`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#t:Predicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the following doesn't directly answer the question of *does such a class exist?*, I still find it worthwhile to point out that a composable approach to input validation is to use an `Applicative` sum type.

I'll start with `Either`, since this is built into the `base` library that comes with GHC. It's actually not the best choice for validation, but I'll get back to that further down.

You can write fine-grained validation functions that return `Either` values, for example:

```
validatePositive :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> Either String a
validatePositive p = if p > 0 then Right p else Left "Not a positive number."
```

In this example, I'm just using a `String` to return error messages, but you may probably want to use something better typed, on which you can pattern-match.

```
*Q57153650> validatePositive (-1)
Left "Not a positive number."
*Q57153650> validatePositive 0
Left "Not a positive number."
*Q57153650> validatePositive 1
Right 1
```

Assume that you've also written validation functions for `Customer` and `ShoppingItem`:

```
validateCustomer :: Customer -> Either String Customer
validateCustomer = -- ...

validateItem :: ShoppingItem -> Either String ShoppingItem
validateItem = -- ...
```

(I'm just showing the types of the functions here, since I don't know how `Customer` or `ShoppingItem` are defined.)

You can now [compose all of these validation functions](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/11/05/applicative-validation) like this:

```
validateOrder :: ShoppingOrder -> Either String ShoppingOrder
validateOrder (ShoppingOrder c i q) =
  ShoppingOrder <$> validateCustomer c <*> validateItem i <*> validatePositive q
```

This illustrates the concept:

```
*Q57153650> :t validOrder
validOrder :: ShoppingOrder
*Q57153650> invalidOrder = validOrder { quantity = (-1) }
*Q57153650> validateOrder validOrder
Right (ShoppingOrder {customer = ..., item = ..., quantity = 2})
*Q57153650> validateOrder invalidOrder
Left "Not a positive number."
```

When you have a valid order, the result of validation is a `Right` value; if anything is incorrect, the result is a `Left` value that indicates what went wrong.

A limitation of the built-in `Either` type's `Applicative` instance is that if *more* than one thing is incorrect, you only get a message about the first incorrect (sub)value.

When it comes to data validation, one often wants to accumulate all the errors in (e.g.) a list, so that one can display a list of problems to the client. As the article I linked to above explains, you can do that by modifying the `Applicative` instance to collect all errors.

You don't have to implement such a type yourself, though, since various packages already do that. One that I'm aware of is [the validation package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/validation), that I do admit, however, I've never used in a real project.